# how to show data with edit.php style in my plugin page wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

i want show all row of table of my plugin in plugin page.
they are many and for show as standard i want use **edit.php** of *wordpress* style how do this.
Should I only use WordPress CSS classes?
exactly like this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/185DP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the `WP_List_Table` class, many plugins extend this class to create their own WP looking admin tables. I've done this myself on some projects and it's doable.

**PLEASE NOTE**, See the following WP notice:

> This class's access is marked as private. That means it is not
>   intended for use by plugin and theme developers as it is subject to
>   change without warning in any future WordPress release. If you would
>   still like to make use of the class, you should make a copy to use and
>   distribute with your own project, or else use it at your own risk.

`WP_List_Table` [info here.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table)
Using `WP_List_Table` in your own plugin, [info here.](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-wp_list_table-to-create-wordpress-admin-tables/)

Regards, Bjorn

Comment: I succeeded with [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-wp_list_table-to-create-wordpress-admin-tables/) tutorial.